# Removing input element from form that has a value result in website crash

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-maps-api-3

I have a form which includes a series of input fields, I also add input fields dynamically with javascript to this form. I am trying to remove these elements dynamically as well with the following code:

```
var catchMarkers = [];
var fishingtripMarker;
var catchIdCounter = 0;
function placeCatchMarker(position)
{
catchMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
});
catchMarker.set("id", catchIdCounter);
AddCatchInput(catchIdCounter);
catchIdCounter++;
//Right click listener
markerListener = google.maps.event.addListener(catchMarker, 'rightclick', function(event) {
    //removing inputs from form
    var fish = document.getElementById('Fish'+this.get("id"));
    var weight = document.getElementById('Weight'+this.get("id"));
    fish.parentNode.removeChild(fish);
    weight.parentNode.removeChild(weight);

    //removing marker
    this.setMap(null);
    var index = catchMarkers.indexOf(this);
    catchMarkers.splice(index, 1);
});
catchMarkers.push(catchMarker);
```

}

I create these inputfields with this code:

```
function AddCatchInput($id)
{
var container = document.getElementById("myform");
var select = document.createElement("select");
select.setAttribute("id", "Fish"+$id);
var option;
option = document.createElement("option");
option.setAttribute("value", "1");
option.innerHTML = "Trout";
select.appendChild(option);
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.id = "Weight" + $id;
container.appendChild(select);
container.appendChild(input);
}
```

Everything works fine until I try to remove these input fields when any of the forms inputfields have values, then the site crashes, and I cant figure out why.

Comment: Better check the browser console for any errors.

Comment: Please define 'crashes'

Comment: Can you post a complete code example that allows us to reproduce the issue? And whenever possible a jsFiddle.net example.

Comment: "Inspected target has crashed. Once it reloads we will attach to it automatically."

Comment: You're using a string in your `get()` method (which is a jQuery method  btw), when it takes an index? Did you mean to use `getAttribute()`?

Comment: its alot of code including google maps javascript api v3, is that possible?

Comment: you mean in the getElementById() method?

Comment: Unfortunately, you probably have to remove all the extra code until you have a small reproducible sample you can post. Also what is `this` in your first code sample?

Comment: I have updated the code in my post now, Im using google maps api to add markers, when i add a marker i add the inputs to the forms, and when i delete the marker i delete the inputs added by that marker.

Comment: site is getting totally crashed? check your server whether something functionality is getting break(in case if it has)..

Comment: the get() method works, as I said in the post, everything works fine until I add values to anyone of the forms input fields and then tries to remove a marker, then the site crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obviously a bug(in chrome) related to the rightclick-event.

The issue is not the fact that the input has a value, it happens when the input has the focus when you rightclick on the marker, crash-demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/57V72/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/57V72/)

possible solution: remove the focus from the input before the rightclick fires, e.g. onmousedown:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(catchMarker, 'mousedown', function (event) {
    document.getElementById('Weight' + this.get("id")).blur();
});
```

demo without crash: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/57V72/1/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/57V72/1/)

You should report this bug.

Comment: I will definitely try that as soon as I can and accept this as the answer if it works! Thanks for your answer man :)

Comment: it stops the website from crashing, but it makes it so I can´t drag the markers anymore, and I cant figure out another way to do it.

Comment: hm, yes I can, it must be something else in my code then